# Existence of a natural linear isomorphism between certain group rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given a set $X$, let $J(X)$ denote the free monoid on $X$ and $F(X)$ denote the free group on $X$.

Let $k$ be a field of prime characteristic. Since $F(X)$ and $J(X)$ have the same cardinality, there is a linear isomorphism between their group rings $k[F(X)]$ and $k[J(X)]$. Can a linear isomorphism $f_X:k[F(X)]\to k[J(X)]$ be found that is natural in $X$?

Note that I require that the isomorphism only be linear since any algebra homomorphism $k[F(X)]\to k[J(X)]$ is necessarily trivial, since there are no multiplicative inverses in $k[J(X)]$.

Comment: You probably want to add some "non-triviality" condition, right, as the map "identity on $k$" and zero on $F(X) - \{1\}$ seems to give a natural $k[F(X)] \to k\langle X\rangle$ ...

Comment: yes. I missed that. I'll add this to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the answer is yes. Here are the details.

By definition $k[F(X)]$ is a $k$-vector space having as basis the elements of the group $F(X)$, in the similar way $k[J(X)]$ it the $k$-vector space having basis the elements of the monoid $J(X)$.

The elements of $J(X)$ can be represented (up to isomorphism) as finite sequences of the form $\langle(x_i,n_i)\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k}$ where $x_i \in X$ and $n_i \in N\setminus \{0\}$ and for every $i=1,\dots,k-1$ we have that $x_i \ne x_{i+1}$.

In a similar way the elements of $F(X)$ can be represented as finite sequences $\langle x_i,n_i\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k}$ where $x_i \in X$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$, the inequalities $x_i \ne x_{i+1}$ holds for $i=1,\dots,k-1$ and for every $i$ we also have that $n_i \in \mathbb Z \setminus\{0\}$

Now there's a well know bijection between $\mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, which is the one defined ad
$$f \colon \mathbb N \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$$
$$f(2n-1) = n$$
$$f(2n) = - n$$
where $n \geq 1$

From this bijection we can build up a bijection between the families $J(X)$ and $F(X)$ mapping 
$$\varphi \colon J(X) \to F(X)$$
$$\langle (x_i,n_i)\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k} \in J(X) \stackrel{\varphi}{\mapsto} \langle(x_i,f(n_i))\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k} \in F(X)$$

For every function $g \colon X \to Y$ would give a homomorphism of monoids $J(g) \colon J(X) \to J(Y)$ such that 
$$J(g)(\langle (x_i,n_i)\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k} = \langle(g(x_i),n_i)\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k}$$ 
and similarily the homomorphism $F(g) \colon F(X) \to F(Y)$ would be such that 
$$F(g)(\langle (x_i,n_i)\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k} = \langle (g(x_i),n_i)\rangle_{i=1,\dots,k}$$
So these morphisms act on the first component of each element of the finite sequence, while the $\varphi$ acts on the second component, so they commute and this should provide the naturality condition.

Comment: Essentially you gave a set bijection $J(X)\to F(X)$ natural in $X$. The group ring functor then induces a natural linear isomorphism $k[J(X)]\to k[F(X)]$. Thank you!

Comment: @ColinTan You're welcome.